# WMS returns but WFS does not return same SRS and BBOX values

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, wfs, getfeature

I am using WMS and WFS services on GeoServer. My WMS query returns the image result for features:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=Gis:Poi&version=1.1.1&useCors=false&height=256&width=256&srs=EPSG:3067&&BBOX=316600,6838986,316605,6838991&

But I am using same BBOX and SRS values for WFS service but does not return any value.

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsName=EPSG:3067&typeName=Gis:Poi&BBOX=316600,6838986,316605,6838991&service=WFS&

Comment: Five by five meter box? Are you sure that you have any POI inside your BBOX?

Answer (score 2):

See my other reply about difference between WMS and WFS:
[WFS and WMS query SRS parameter and BBOX usage](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225535/wfs-and-wms-query-srs-parameter-and-bbox-usage)

You did not specify what's the SRS for the BBOX (if you don't, GeoServer assumes it's the native SRS of the data).

Comment: I use same parameters (bbox and srs) but data comes wit wms and does not come with wfs. my question is so clear.

Comment: Did you read carefully the linked answer? In WFS 1.1.0 and higher you must define the SRS for output and for BBOX separately if you do not use the default SRS for both. Use BBOX=316600,6838986,316605,6838991,EPSG:3067 and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what the return format is e.g. `outputFormat=application/json&`

You also need to specify which service you want! e.g. `service=WFS&`

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&srsName=EPSG:3067&typeName=Gis:Poi&BBOX=316600,6838986,316605,6838991&outputFormat=application/json&service=WFS&
```

Comment: outputFromat returns no result `{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":0,"features":[]}`. but there is some data here. I can see with wms.

Comment: what format is the source layer? what geometry type?

Comment: Source is EPSG:4326 in database. But wfs service getting data.

Comment: OK, and what sort of data? .shp .geojson? point, line, polygon, multi?

Comment: Data geometry is point. But is does not metter, no data returns. Geoserver connects to postgis and get data.

Comment: Have you tried a GetCapabilites request?

Comment: WFS does not require outputformat, it has a default format which is GML 3 for WFS version 1.1.0. Test with this http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&TypeName=topp:states&maxFeatures=1